# What 90s kids fantasy TV series featured a world in a box, and possibly Andrew Sachs?

Tags: story-identification

When I was in Year 3 of Primary School (around 1997/8) we watched a serial of fantasy TV programmes. They were short (15-20 minutes) and I remember there being a box with a world inside it called Heritron or something similar.

I also remember [Andrew Sachs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Sachs) (the bloke who played Manuel in Fawlty Towers) being in it, but I may be remembering it wrong.

Does anyone know what this program was?

Comment: “When I was in Year 3 of Primary School” — couldja tell us when that actually was? We’re not your parents.

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot that bit, It was around 1997/8 ish

Comment: No worries, good stuff. I’ve added Manuel’s real name too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick Google for “Heritron” suggests that this was the *Look & Read* classic *[The Legend of the Lost Keys (1998)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_the_Lost_Keys)*, which did indeed star Andrew Sachs. Well remembered!

Looks like it’s freely available on YouTube (e.g. [starting here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0U-zk4rDQas)). Bet it wasn’t a patch on *[Geordie Racer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geordie_Racer)* though.